# How do i when click button show results in json file with vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Yes me again!

[This is my project](https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/JaWGNW)

I want to pull the data from the json file when I fill in the required fields and press the button.

For example, let's write the developer part to the jobs section. then select istanbul as an option and click Find!.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    founded: [],
    search: ""
  },
  created() {
    fetch("job.json")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.founded = res.items;
      });
  },
  computed:{
      filteredFounded: function(){
          return this.founded.filter((items)=> {
              return items.positionName.match(this.search)
          });
      }
  }
});
```

```html
    <div class="header">
        <h4>Get Job</h4>
    </div>



    <div id="app" class="nested">
        <div class="card w-50">
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="job" v-model="search" placeholder="Job...">
                <select name="" class="city" id="">
                    <option value="Seçiniz">Seçiniz</option>
                    <option value="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
                    <option value="Ankara">Ankara</option>
                    <option value="İzmir">İzmir</option>
                    <option value="Çanakkale">Çanakkale</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="find">
                <button>Find!</button>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body" v-for="items in filteredFounded">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{items.companyName}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.positionName | to-uppercase}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.cityName}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.townName}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{items.distance}}</p>
                <a href="#" class=" btn-primary">Go!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue:

- the view updates on each form change since you bound the `card-body` repeating `div` directly to the filtering process, so the "Find!" button isn't used
- you don't consider the city selection

To fix these, bind a model to the city selector, and declare separate variables for the JSON data and for the selected data:

```
<select name="" class="city" id="" v-model="city">
```

and:

```
data: {
  search: "",
  sourceJobs: [],
  selectedJobs: [],
  city: ""
}
```

Then put you JSON data in `sourceJobs` on creation:

```
fetch("job.json").then(function (res) {
  this.sourceJobs = res.json();
});
```

Side note: this architecture will not be viable for large JSON data, maybe you should consider filtering data through a call to your back-end API... but that's not the current question.

Now that your form data is bound to `data.search` and `data.city`, and that your pool of jobs is stored in `data.sourceJobs`, you want to have a method (no more `computed`) to filter `data.sourceJobs` and copy the resulting subset in `data.selectedJobs`:

```
methods: {
  selectJobs: function () {
    this.selectedJobs = this.sourceJobs
      .filter((job) => {
        return job.cityName === this.city && job.positionName.match(this.search);
      })
  }
}
```

Finally, call this method when the "Find!" button is clicked:

```
<button v-on:click="selectJobs">Find!</button>
```

In case you change you architecture to go for an API call to do the filtering, then you just need to remove that `created` part and do the API call from within the `selectJobs` method.

*Side, unrelated note: find/found/found (successful result of searching) vs. found/founded/founded (create, build, set a base for something - a city, a company...).*

Comment: I will try this solution that you suggested, my case is: when I write the necessary info into the gaps,- for example job for one gap and for the other gap the city name- I want to see the jobs in that city.

Comment: I never used Vue but I took your code and played with [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgpz7t2q/15/), I believe it works as intended.

Comment: i tryed and failed with your solution :/ but you gave me an idea and its worked. but there is many deficient.